# How do I Remove the last Object in an array list in xna

Tags: c#, arrays, list, xna, xna-4.0

for example I am currently working on a game how would I get rid of the last Projectile in the list instead of all of them.
Here is my shot code.

```
           if (mouse.RightButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                if (Plist.Count < 100)
                {

                    Plist.Add(p);
                    f = 0;
                    p.Position = gamePlayer.Position;

                }


                    p.Target = new Vector2(mouse.X + gameCamera.Position.X, mouse.Y + gameCamera.Position.Y) + randomv;

            }

            foreach (Projectile po in Plist)
            {


                if (Vector2.Distance(po.Position, po.Target) < 10)
                {
                    p.Remove = true;
                }
            }
            if (p.Remove == true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Plist.Count; i++)
                {
                    Plist.RemoveAt(i);

                }
                p.Remove = false;
            }
```

Comment: If you only want exactly 100 projectiles at a time why not put it in a stack?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest changing `PList` from an `ArrayList` and making it a `List<Projectile>` instead.

Given that, you could eliminate your `Projectile.Remove` flag and your loop, and just use:

```
PList.RemoveAll(po => po.Remove || Vector2.Distance(po.Position, po.Target) < 10);
```

This will remove all `Projectile` instances with `Remove` set or where the distance is `<10`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `p` is, but it doesn't look like it's associated with any particular instance of a projectile.  you're using the same flag for all the projectiles at once

If you just want a new list of projectiles that deserve to exist, the easiest thing to use is linq:

```
Plist = Plist.Where(po -> Vector2.Distance(po.Position, po.Target) >= 10).ToList();
```

Comment: This won't work with an `ArrayList`, btw, which is what the OP specified, but is reasonable if the OP switches to `List<T>`.